# Running a Livecode Stack from command line on headless server

Tags: livecode

I have a Livecode stack which I use for processing server reports. Currently, it reads files off of my Linux server (CentOS) from my desktop. I would like to set up a cron job on the server itself which would run everything for me. Here are my questions:

1. is it possible to run a stack from command line on a headless server (and how)?
2. is it possible to pass parameters in the command line to the stack?
3. how can I present some text in my terminal that will indicate that it worked?

For my purposes, it does not matter if the stack is compiled into a standalone, or left as a stack and run through an installation of Livecode on the machine.

My guess, is that in my openStack handler, I am going to toss in all of the handlers that would normally run when I press the button that initiates my report, and then end the openStack handler with some sort of shutdown code command.

Answer (score 1):

If you install community server (or commercial server), the following script will run on the server and demonstrates how to access command line arguments;

```
#!/path/to/livecode/server/livecode-server
<?lc
put "arguments: " & $# & LF
put "first argument: " & $0 & LF
put "next argument: " & $1 & LF
```

You can also open stacks as library files (check out start using in the dictionary) and access their handlers, etc. from your scripts.